Request Handling in quarkus
I would like to process the request when the controller method has a custom annotation that I created in quarkus.
@Slf4j
@Provider
@Priority(5000)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExampleFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

 @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        String body = getBody(requestContext);
        log.info("Request is: {}", body);

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        log.info("Response is: {}", responseContext.getEntity().toString());
        //I would like here to find the handling controller method of the incoming request and check if it is annotated with my custom annotation.
    }

    private String getBody(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestContext.getEntityStream()));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            body.append(line);
        }
        return body.toString();
    }
}

In spring boot I am using RequestMappingHandlerMapping with the request
var handlerChain = handlerMapping.getHandler((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handlerChain.getHandler();
handlerMethod.hasMethodAnnotation(MY_CUSTOM_ANNOTATION.class)
//do some stuff here


and I can find if it is annotated.
What can I use in quarkus in order to achieve the same?

You can do something like this:
@Slf4j
@Provider
@Priority(5000)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExampleFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;


 @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        String body = getBody(requestContext);
        log.info("Request is: {}", body);

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        log.info("Response is: {}", responseContext.getEntity().toString());

        resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().isAnnotationPresent(MY_CUSTOM_ANNOTATION.class)

    }
}


Can I ask you something else in the above snippet? When I read the body from the requestContext using the stream, then the body in the actual code is null because the stream is now empty.
How can I prevent this?
Code updated

You are welcome. You would need to copy the stream essentially and then call setEntityStream
